# Where to put Global List of object used in the Application C#?

Tags: c#

Where to put Global List of object used in the Application C#?

Let's say I got a list of category, which I want to be able to use any time, without having to retrieve these categories each time I need to use it.
What I will do is to retrieve the categories and store it to the List of category at startup. Then I will use this List of category, to update the items if there is changes to the items or access the items when I need to do operations on the time.

How can I do this?

My application is splitted up in a console layer, dataaccess layer and Logic layer. Where do I usually store this kind of List in order to be able to access it any time?

Right now I'm having a

```
public dynamic Categories{ get; set; }
```

Which I save the data to.

I'm using dependency injection, Ninject.

Comment: Be aware that the collection needs to be thread safe if updates to it are done after startups. (while reading might be happening)

Comment: Startup of what application? A desktop application or a single-server web application could just store the data in a static property. A *web* application though would need shared storage

Comment: 99.99% of the time `dynamic` points to a design problem

Comment: It's an console application for windows server. 

I'm going to change dynamic to the actual datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Please create as static.

```
public static dynamic Categories{ get; set; }
```

Comment: CAn I just use public dynamic Categories{ get; set; }?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need DI for that, but one thing you could do is declare a static class lets say CategoriesCache which has a static list (or any kind of approporiate datastructure) and fetch the list at application startup. After that you can use that list. Maybe store it at app shutdown.

If you want to solve it with DI I can provide you with a snippet (SimpleInjector, but you can tailor it to your needs) for a similar problem:

```
public class ServiceBootstrapper
{
serviceContainer.Register<IApplicationSettings>(() => ApplicationSettings.Read(), Lifestyle.Singleton);
}
```

Note: This isn't a proper thing to do if your categories ever change during app lifecycle.

Comment: I'm using DI right now in the application.
Do you mean that I should get the data and store it to a file, then for each time I need this data I have to retrieve it from the file?

Comment: No. What I mean is that you application should have a static class. For example Categories cache, which will have a static List<Categories> and when your bootstrapping completes you call a method (which you have to write) that uses the repository to retrieve data and initializes this static field on the static class once. This will be stored in the memory not in a file. Of course you should consider things like what will you do if the categories change in the meantime (e.g. multi-user environment) do you have to "invalidate the cache" and so on :)

Comment: Could this be done without using static, but like dependency inject?

Comment: Well you could also do something like a custom factory which always returns a singleton instance of IEnumerable<Categories> but it's more complicated. https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Providers,-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context

Comment: could you provide an example? I'm using ninject for most of my interfaces throughout the host / console atm.